# KineticJS TextPath data attribute

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to get a curved Text using KineticJS.

What my goal is:

- Have KineticJS to create a canvas with curved Text on a TextPath
- Center that Text
- Have a  field which updates the curved text onkeyup
- Have a possibility to adjust the radius of the curve
- The canvas made by KineticJS should be hidden but create a .png which is visible
- Save the .png file on the server

What I already have reached:

- Have KineticJS to create a canvas with curved Text on a TextPath
- Center that Text
- Have a  field which updates the curved text onkeyup
- The canvas made by KineticJS is hidden but creates a .png which is visible
- Save the .png file on the server

So, all I need is a possibility to adjust the radius of the curve which seems pretty hard because I just don't get how the data attribute from Kinetic.TextPath works.

I figured out that the first value (Mxx.xx, xx.xx) is the offset of the whole Path but I don't understand how the following values (cxx.xx, xx.xx and sxx.xx, xx.xx) work.

I started searching the web for a explanation yesterday but didn't find anything useful.

I really would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably noticed, in `Kinetic.TextPath` you will have some properties like `text` and `data`. In `text` you specify a string to be shown in the textpath and in `data` you can define a SVG data string that will shape your textpath.

That SVG data string can contain some elements such as: M, L, H, V, C, S, Q, T, A and Z.

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp) explains each one of those elements:

- M = moveto
- L = lineto
- H = horizontal lineto
- V = vertical lineto
- C = curveto
- S = smooth curveto
- Q = quadratic Bézier curve
- T = smooth quadratic Bézier curveto
- A = elliptical Arc
- Z = closepath

The numbers that follow each element are the coordinates of the point.

Example of SVG path:

```
<path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
```

KineticJS website provides a TextPath [example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-text-path-tutorial/) that you can use as a reference for you custom textpath.